# Plotting Pandas DataFrames in to Pie Charts using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

Is it possible to print a `DataFrame` as a pie chart using matplotlib? [The Pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html) on chart visualization has instructions for plotting lot of chart types including bar, histogram, scatter plot etc. But pie chart is missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.pie(DataFrame([1,2,3]))
```

seems to work as expected. If the DataFrame has more than one column, it will raise.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It works fine. But how to put chart labels based on DataFrame column names?

Comment: Read the documentation for ``pie``, and use the DataFrame's ``.columns``.

Answer (score 33):

To plot a pie chart from a dataframe `df` you can use Panda's [`plot.pie`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html):

```
df.plot.pie(y='column_name')
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'activity': ['Work', 'Sleep', 'Play'],
                   'hours': [8, 10, 6]})
df.set_index('activity', inplace=True)
print(df)
#               hours
# activity       
# Work          8
# Sleep        10
# Play          6
plot = df.plot.pie(y='hours', figsize=(7, 7))
```

Note that the labels of the pie chart are the index entries, this is the reason for using `set_index` to set the index to `activity`.

To style the plot, you can use all those arguments that can be passed to [DataFrame.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot), here an example showing percentages:

```
plot = df.plot.pie(y='hours', title="Title", legend=False, \
                   autopct='%1.1f%%', explode=(0, 0, 0.1), \
                   shadow=True, startangle=0)
```

[image: Pie chart from Pandas dataframe]

Comment: Funny how yours is the only one with an image. It also highlights other useful parameters. This should be the best answer.

Answer (score 22):

Pandas has this built in to the `pd.DataFrame.plot()`. All you have to do is use `kind='pie'` flag and tell it which column you want (or use `subplots=True` to get all columns). This will automatically add the labels for you and even do the percentage labels as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.Data.plot(kind='pie')
```

To make it a little more customization you can do this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=200)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

df.Data.plot(kind='pie', ax=ax, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=270, fontsize=17)
```

Where you tell the `DataFrame` that `ax=ax`. You can also use all the normal `matplotlib plt.pie()` flags as shown above.

Comment: This solution is confusing and it seems you assume a number of things. What is df? What is Data?