# Making multiple pie charts out of a pandas dataframe (one for each column)

Tags: pandas, pie-chart

My question is similar to *[Making multiple pie charts out of a pandas dataframe (one for each row).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787006/making-multiple-pie-charts-out-of-a-pandas-dataframe-one-for-each-row)*

However, instead of each row, I am looking for each column in my case.
I can make pie chart for each column, however, as I have 12 columns the pie charts are too much close to each other.

I have used this code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(10, 6))

for i, (idx, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    ax = axes[i // 3, i % 3]
    row = row[row.gt(row.sum() * .01)]
    ax.pie(row, labels=row.index, startangle=30)
    ax.set_title(idx)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.2)
```

and I have the following result

[image: ![enter image description here]

But I want is on the other side. I need to have 12 pie charts (becuase I have 12 columns) and each pie chart should have 4 sections (which are leg, car, walk, and bike)

and if I write this code

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,3)
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax = axes[i // 3, i % 3]
    plt.plot(df[col])
```

then I have the following results:
[image]

and if I use :

```
plot = df.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(17, 8),labels=['pt','car','walk','bike'])
```

then I have the following results:
[image]
Which is quite what I am looking for. but it is not possible to read the pie charts. if it can produce in more clear output, then it is better.

Answer (score 0):

As in your linked post I would use matplotlib.pyplot for this. The accepted answer uses `plt.subplots(2, 3)` and I would suggest doing the same for creating two rows with each 3 plots in them.
Like this:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,3)
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax = axes[i // 3, i % 3]
    ax.plot(df[col])
```

Comment: I have writen plt.subplots(2, 3)  but it didnt work.

Comment: As in your linked post you need to access the axes and figures for each subplot. Really, it is the same as in your linked post, where the accepted answer calls each `ax` and plots on it.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I need to draw pie charts for each culumn not for rows. I cannot use iterrows or I dont have row or idx

Comment: I have added a foto of the result when I used the code from my example

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have eddited my question.

Comment: and ```plt.plot.pie(df[col])``` results to error 'function' object has no attribute 'pie'

Comment: [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html) says you can just pass the column name as a parameter to plot.pie

Comment: Please see the results in my eddited question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I understood that if I swap rows and columns

```
df_sw = df.T
```

Then I can use the code in the examples:
[Making multiple pie charts out of a pandas dataframe (one for each row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787006/making-multiple-pie-charts-out-of-a-pandas-dataframe-one-for-each-row)