# I want to create a pie chart using a dataframe column in python

Tags: python

I want to create a Pie chart using single column of my dataframe, say my column name is 'Score'. I have stored scores in this column as below :

```
Score

.92
.81
.21
.46
.72
.11
.89
```

Now I want to create a pie chart with the range in percentage.
Say 0-0.4 is 30% , 0.4-0.7 is 35 % , 0.7+ is 35% .
I am using the below code using

```
df1['bins'] = pd.cut(df1['Score'],bins=[0,0.5,1], labels=["0-50%","50-100%"])
df1 = df.groupby(['Score', 'bins']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

df1.plot.pie(subplots=True,figsize=(8, 3))
```

With the above code I am getting the Pie chart, but i don’t know how i can do this using percentage.

[my pie chart look like this for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K2Ta.png)

Comment: I don't understand what it should look like. Where are the percentages coming from?

Comment: My query is that only...I want to use percentage instead...ther percentage i mentioned in my question is just an example.

Comment: Are you asking how you can make a slice represent the relative sixe as to how many "scores" fit within a particular range? Say, from your data, 2/7th of the data is between 0 and .30, so a slice of this range should be 2/7 of the whole circle.. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: yeah lets consider the exact data that i have given, so i want to create pie chart with three slices ranges (0- 0.4, 0.4-0.8, 0.8-1), 1 slice should tell about the percentage of data coming in first range i.e 2/7, 2nd slice should tell about the percentage of data in in 2nd range i.e 2/7 again, 3rd one will contain 3/7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cutting the dataframe up into bins is the right first step. After which, you can use [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True` in order to get relative frequencies of values in the `bins` column. This will let you see percentage of data across ranges that are defined in the bins.

In terms of plotting the pie chart, I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but it seemed like you would like to display the correct legend values and the percentage values in each slice of the pie.

[pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) is a good place to see all parameters that can be passed into the plot method. You can specify what are your `x` and `y` columns to use, and by default, the dataframe index is used as the legend in the pie plot.

To show the percentage values per slice, you can use the `autopct` parameter as well. As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24789218/3353866), you can use all the normal matplotlib `plt.pie()` flags in the plot method as well.

Bringing everything together, this is the resultant code and the resultant chart:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [0.92,0.81,0.21,0.46,0.72,0.11,0.89]})
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Score'], bins=[0,0.4,0.7,1], labels=['0-0.4','0.4-0.7','0.7-1'], right=True)

bin_percent = pd.DataFrame(df['bins'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100)
plot = bin_percent.plot.pie(y='bins', figsize=(5, 5), autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

[Plot of Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BODP.png)

Comment: Superrrr!! it really helped me to get the exact thing what i was looking for.Thanks a ton.